# Abstract Algebra - Permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm asked to show that $(1,2,3) \in S_3$ generates a subgroup which is normal.

I know that I could show it explicitly but that would be tedious. I think it may have to do with the fact that $(1,2,3)$ generates all even permutations but I'm sure there's something I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, showing it directly would be relatively untedious as far as getting your hands dirty with group theory is concerned. There are only six elements in $S_3$, and $\langle(123)\rangle$ has three elements so it only has two cosets (where did I get "two" from?), so there isn't much work involved. I urge you to do the problem first by going this route. This kind of practice is necessary.

For an abstract, and perhaps elegant, approach, you can argue that $\langle(123)\rangle$ is the only subgroup with some property (and explain why it is the only one), a property which is invariant under conjugation. This will tell you the subgroup is conjugation-invariant, i.e. normal (quiz: how does it tell us this?). Can you figure out the property? It's very basic: I mentioned it in the first paragraph.

It's possible that the meat of this argument (how being the unique subgroup with a conjugation-invariant property implies the subgroup is conjugation-invariant) is what you're struggling with. But you have the right idea since the argument I gave above generalizes to showing $A_n\triangleleft S_n$ using the same argument with even permutations (although one could also show it's index two).

Answer (score 2):

I think that the standard way to do that is simply by brute force.
You have just to check 3 conjugations of the subgroup by the 3 elements outside of it, process that is neither hard nor long.

Anyway, a not-so-tedious way to do that is to show that it is the kernel of the (surjective) group homomorphism
$$\begin{aligned}\phi: S_3&\longrightarrow C_2\\
\sigma&\longmapsto \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)
\end{aligned}$$

Source: Take a look at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation#Properties).

Comment: Re: checking conjugacy classes. Are you suggesting OP show that the subgroup is a union of conjugacy classes? (This is equivalent to being normal.) +1 for kernel of homomorphism.

Comment: No, I intended just that the definition can be checked directly (stable under conjugation by elements of the group). Since it is already know that it is a subgroup, there are only the 3 elements outside of it that can mess the things up.

This gives just 3 conjugacy classes generated by the subgroup to be checked (they should turn out to be the subgroup itself).

Comment: "three conjugacy classes generated by the subgroup" - so, conjugacy classes of subgroups, not of elements?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking the sets $gHg^{-1}$. Maybe they are not called conjugacy classes in English? If so, I'm sorry about that! :) Unfortunately I had my courses in my mother language :)

Comment: Ah, I see. In English the phrase "conjugacy classes" means conjugacy classes of elements, like $\{gxg^{-1}:g\in G\}$, unless the phrase is explicitly followed by "of subgroups," in which case we mean $\{gHg^{-1}:g\in G\}$.

Comment: Ah, great to know! Thanks! :) So maybe it is better if I reformulate the statemente in the answer :)